# Is the loop of a strong deformation retract a strong deformation retract?

Tags: general-topology

Let $A\hookrightarrow X$ be a strong deformation retract (of based spaces). Is it true that $\Omega A\hookrightarrow \Omega X$ is a strong deformation retract, where $\Omega$ denote the loop space?

Comment: The title and the question do not agree. Is $A \to X$ required to be a cofibration or not?

Comment: I've edited the question, but the difference is minor (if not irrelevant if we work over WHCG).